# Merge data for a set of database tables in SSIS across databases

Tags: ssis

Is there a way in SSIS to effectively synchronize data in multiple tables with foreign key constraints across databases on different servers? Is it with TableDiff which is a command line interface or some other built in tasks?

On top of this, the tables that need to be synchronized have foreign key constraints with other tables outside the set. That means we might need to first disable all the constraints before running the task?

Comment: There is definitely nothing magic in SSIS that does this. When you say synchronise, do you mean at the end of the sync, all databases will hold the same data? The old fashioned way of doing this is merge replication. (I assume you mean SQL Server - please clarify)

Comment: Yes, to have the database tables involved to have the same data after synchronization. And initially for SQL server but it may expand to Oracle etc.

Comment: For SQL server I suggest you investigate merge replication. There’s probably a similar tool for Oracle. But fundamentally you have to decide:  when two db’s change a record with the same key, which one wins?

Comment: It will be just one way, for source to destination. I do not need the destination to merge back the database back to the source. It is kind of loading the lookup tables from a production environment to test environment(s)